# How to delete windows partition from ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

How do i delete windows partition from Ubuntu? I have the FBI virus on my windows partition and need to delete it from Ubuntu OS.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it from gparted. You can also fire up an Ubuntu start up CD and use gparted from there.